# div doesn't fit content

Tags: css, width

I have a problem that div doesn't fit content when it contain long words. It just take max-width.

Screenshot:

http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/3253/photondf.png

I want div to take same width as content without javaScript.

HTML

```
<div class="div">
    <p>fkjdajfkdjfkdjfkdfjkdfjkdfjdfdjkfkjfdkdfioiewtiovvuiocuvicxvocxvuiocxvucioxbuvbhxjk
    civuiozxviopucvicvuvjcizoxvopcxvpiovxzijpvxzicovpzvjijopcvzxpvjiocvpjzvicvzpjvci.</p>
<div>
```

CSS

```
.div {
    float: left;
    background:red;
    max-width: 900px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole HTML file?  It is possible another parent DIV or style is preventing this as well.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly trying to get the div to do? Did you want it to scale down to the size of the content but be no bigger than 900px?

Comment: Yes! I want div to scale down to the size of the content.

Comment: But does there have to be a max width of 900px? or will there be a parent div around it?

Comment: Yes it have to be max width of 900px.

Answer (score 0):

Try `width: auto;` but keep `max-width` if you don't want your div to be larger than 900px.

Answer (score 0):

Well well, there are couple of problems here.

1. The content in `p` doesn't have any space at all. In other word, it won't be able to "split" the word on multiple rows. And your div does actually have the correct width.
2. Unless you really don't want to split it over multiple lines. You can define `overflow` on the div to either `auto` or `hidden`. In this case, `auto` will add scrollbars and `hidden` will simply hide the content that goes over.
3. If `overflow` on either the `p` or the `div`, You can actually force word-wrapping in css3: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp
4. Since you defined a width for the div, it really always used that width and never more. (Don't count the overflowing text as bigger than the div). The overflowing text shouldn't be taken into account when calculating layout size and position of other div around this one.

Btw, a really long string like that isn't really a good "use case" if you have problem when there are actually spaces. You should paste it here instead of that.

**edit**

Your div can't "fit" the content with long words, it will spread to the maximum width possible and then when the maximum width is reached, it will wrap to an other line. If the word is bigger than the div it will overflow.

**edit 2**

If you really want to do that, there is a way. But this is quite ugly. You'll have to add a `<br />` after each long words. If you're passing the text within a template engine, you can even make the `<br />` replace your spaces with css. But to be honest, just don't do that.

Comment: It is a space on the end of the first line, so there is two strings. One string is in first line and the other in in second line, but the problem is that div doesn't take the width of the longer string but it take the max-width.

Comment: The problem is that since you don't have any break line, It will eat all space and once it reach max-width, it will try to wrap to an other line if its possible. Or it will overflow. That said even if there is a space after the first word, there is not enough space to put the second word. But the layout calculation will no check the div size everytime something wraps. It will recalculate width only on each new lines. (after a "<br>" for example)